# Chrome App shortcut Always opens New Window instead of Focus on existing

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, window-focus

I've looked everywhere still didn't find an answer to this.

In Chrome we can create a shortcut to desktop from a url, and open it like an App in a new window (like **Google Calendar**).

If I click on the Shortcut twice, it opens two separate windows of the shortcut.
How to make it focus on the open window when I click it the second (or more) times.